Definition of additive category
In the book "Several Complex Variables with Connections to Algebraic Geometry and Lie Groups" I found following definition of additive category:

for each ordered pair of objects $A, B$, the set $\operatorname{Hom}(A, B)$ is given the structure of an (additive) abelian group, in such a way that the composition law is bilinear;
there is an object $0$ in category so that $\operatorname{Hom}(0, 0) = \{0\}$;
to each ordered pair of objects $A, B$, there is assigned a third object $ A \oplus B$ and an isomorphism of functors  $\operatorname{Hom} (A, \cdot) \oplus \operatorname{Hom}(B,\cdot) \cong \operatorname{Hom} (A \oplus B, \cdot) $
for each ordered pair of objects $A, B$, there is also an isomorphism of functors $\operatorname{Hom} (\cdot, A) \oplus \operatorname{Hom}(\cdot,B) \cong \operatorname{Hom} (\cdot,A \oplus B) $

There is also exercise thay first three conditions imply forth.
I don't know much about category theory but other definiyions I found demand existance of coproducts. So not only objects $ A \oplus B$ but also morphisms $i_1 : A \to A \oplus B$ and $i_2 : A \to A \oplus B$, such that under isomorphism in 3. $f \in \operatorname{Hom} (A \oplus B, C) $ correspond to $f \circ i_1 \oplus f \circ i_2$. Then it can easily be proven that this implies existance of products and that $ A \oplus B$ is biproduct.
So my question is: does first three conditions imply that $ A \oplus B$ as defined there is coproduct in standart definitions?
Thank you!

The third condition is precisely the statement that you have a binary coproduct (even in the sense of enriched categories).

Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I can't understand why it is equivalent to standart definition of coproduct. From third condition we obviously get $i_1 : A \to A \oplus B$ and $i_2 : A \to A \oplus B$ that correspond to identity morphism on  $A \oplus B$ and from this homomorphism $Hom(A \oplus B, C) \to Hom(A,  C) \oplus  Hom(B,  C) : f \to f \circ i_1 \oplus f \circ i_2 $. But why this is isomorphism?

What is $f \circ i_1 \oplus f \circ i_2$ supposed to mean? I suggest you review the definition of coproduct  in terms of representable functors.

As I understand it, it's element of $\operatorname{Hom} (A, C) \oplus \operatorname{Hom}(B, C) $ (basically direct sum of abelian groups) . $f \circ i_1 $ is composition of $i_1 : A \to A \oplus B$ and some $f : A \oplus B \to C$ for some object $C$ in the category. Similarly for $f \circ i_2 $. Morphisms $i_1, i_2$ correspond to identity morphism for $A \oplus B$ in the isomorphism of third conition.

It is indeed the case that $f$ corresponds to $f \circ i_1 + f \circ i_2$ in the direct sum of hom groups. There is a bijection because you have assumed there is an isomorphism. This is a more hands-on way of proving you have a coproduct. But this is immediate if you understand the representable functor definition of (co)limits.

After carefully reading your comments and some definitions, I think I now understand where I got it wrong. I didn't noticed there are morphisms of functors and thought of it just as isomorphisms of all possible abelian groups $\operatorname{Hom} (A, C) \oplus \operatorname{Hom}(B, C)$ and $\operatorname{Hom} (A \oplus B, C) $ for all $C$ without additional conditions. With isomorphism of functors there are also commutativity of squares in definition of morphism of functors and with it equivalence with standart definition of coproduct is clear.
